# In a web browser, how to find out what triggers a hidden CSS class to appear in javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

As a freelance Wordpress developer I find myself thrown into projects where things are just 'broken' - with the problems regularly ending up being some kind of path issue/syntax error/etc in javascript.

I am in the situation right now where I am trying to get something that works in **Site A** to work on **Site B**. Basically the problem involves a mouse over event that causes a div with class name 'overlay-ico' to appear.

I'm sure there must be some kind of debug tool in Chrome, Firefox, etc that allows me to easily do this without reviewing all the source code?

**Update:**
I am familiar with being able to inspect the HTML (at least in a basic way), but I don't see how this shows me what would trigger an event to occur.

I am also know that there is a console, which as I understand it, only outputs errors, or something that has been explicitly directed to console output.

There must be somewhere in the code that is waiting for a mouse over event, that triggers 'overlay-ico' to appear. I'm sure I could do it if I did a search for 'overlay-ico' through all the source code - but I'm thinking there must be a faster way to find it.

Comment: In Chrome, `CTRL + SHIFT + J`.

Comment: You've been making it hard on yourself not knowing about the browsers' debugging tools.

Comment: Right-click>inspect element

Answer (score 2):

In Windows, F12 opens the debug panel in most browsers.

In Chrome, you can inspect an element and then click into the Event Listeners tab in the right pane. That may show what you're after. It's hard to say without seeing it.